# background-position value manipulation

Tags: css

I have a project where I am building slides described inside of an XML file but it requires to allow image positioning of the slides based on offset values.

Now I have Y offsets down pat, only problem now is that I require the ability to offset something in the X by an amount but still keep the %'age value behavior.

So basically is there anyway to have background-position's x start at 50% and then offset it by a pixel amount and keep the relative behavior of the %'age( 50% + offsetInPixels)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with plain CSS (at this point in time, see [Rich Bradshaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981639/background-position-value-manipulation/5982010#5982010)).

You could accomplish that in javascript with something like:

```
var totalWidth = 960;
var xOffset = 10;
el.style.backgroundPosition = ((totalWidth/2) + xOffset) +"px 50px";
```

Comment: what would totalWidth represent in your answer? $(window).width()?

Comment: Stefan, it would represent the totalWidth of the container element.

Comment: the only issue with this is that I lose the self-adjusting positions on window resizing if I give a specific pixel value as opposed to giving it a %'age value like 50%. I need to keep the resizing properties of the %'age but with the ability to shift it by a pixel amount on top of that

Comment: alright im gonna mark yours as answered since it was the closest solution. I wound up figuring it out but it requires some math. basically it boils down to : 
on resize:
$(this).css({'background-position-x' : ($(window).width()/2 - img.width/2)+ offsetX + 'px'});

Comment: To clarify on that further, the image is using the background-attachment fixed property which means its based off the window property and ignores parent object positioning. This javascript allows it to have the 50% behavior and then offset it by whatever amount

Answer (score 4):

You can do this, but it isn't widely supported.

```
background-position: -moz-calc(50% - 20px) 0;
background-position: calc(50% - 20px) 0;
```

Currently (May 2011) this only works in Firefox 4 and IE9.

See http://caniuse.com/#calc for compatibility.

Comment: My thoughts exactly – makes a change doesn't it! You can see from the way I've written it that I'm assuming webkit will get it eventually!

Comment: It's pretty awesome – can't wait for it to be in a few more browsers, will make a lot of things very very easy when making liquid layouts, or when you can't find a calculator!

Comment: This is exactly what I want but I need a way of doing this perhaps in javascript that works all the way back to IE7 =(

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your best bet is sticking the background image as an image inside the containter... It's bit of a hack, but it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/mhy3r/10/)  Also, consider (As Jesse said) adding `overflow:hidden` if you don't want the bg pouring out.

```
<div id="main" >
<div id="bg"><img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"/>  </div   </div>
```

```
 #main {
 width:400px;
  height:300px;  
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
}
#bg {
 margin-left: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:50%;
  }
```

demonstrated: http://jsfiddle.net/mhy3r/10/

Comment: For your solution to work well, you would need to change a few things. 1) Get rid of `background-attachment: fixed` 2) add `overflow: hidden` to the container. Also if there are any sibling elements within `#main` they would need to be positioned too and you would have to deal with z-index stuff. See updated version here: http://jsfiddle.net/mhy3r/9/

Comment: @jessegavin actually, my original (and even your fix, though that helped) gets finicky on browser resizes. i've redone my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution using CSS3. However, it requires the container to have a fixed size.

HTML:

```
<div id="example">Example</div>
```

CSS:

```
#example {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-position: 10px 10%;
}
```

It's a bit of a hack I guess. Rather than starting the background-position from the left top corner of the border-box, it uses the content-box instead which has 50% (i.e. 100px) padding. Like I said, you will need to know the exact value of 50% padding because writing `padding-left: 50%;` will be interpreted as 50% of the parent element.

If you need the full space inside this container you can put another `<div>` into it with `margin-left: -100px;`